# Subtract between timestamp in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I found a weird thing. If a timestamp value subtract another, then Redshift will return an strange prefix. For example,

> select table1.c_timestamp - table1.c_timestamp from table_1

Expect result should be ZERO or similar something, because these two timestamp values are same.
However, what I received is "5012369 years 4 mons", which I have no idea how does Redshift calculate the result.

Is there anyone can show me some clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to the other answer,
Datediff doesn't exactly subtract, but rather counts the number of times the datepart chosen starts between the two timestamps.

```
datediff(second, '2018-04-10 00:00:00.001','2018-04-10 00:00:00.999')
>> 0
select datediff(second, '2018-04-10 00:00:00.999','2018-04-10 00:00:01.001')
>> 1
```

See: [Datediff documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html)

---

### Edit: this is the way I found of how to perform the OP's task

```
SELECT 
round(((EXTRACT('epoch' FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-05-27 09:59:59.999') - EXTRACT('epoch' FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-05-27 09:59:59.001'))*1000 + EXTRACT(millisecond FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-05-27 09:59:59.999') - EXTRACT(millisecond FROM TIMESTAMP '2018-05-27 09:59:59.001'))::real/1000)
```

Answer (score 5):

The right way to subtract between datetimes is:

`select datediff(seconds, table1.c_timestamp, table1.c_timestamp) from table_1`

Of course, it doesn't make much sense to subtract a timestamp from itself, because that obviously returns 0, but I assume you just run that as a test.